# Defining the nth derivative of inverse trigonometric explicitly instead of recursively

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I found an explicit formula to find the nth derivative of the inverse trigonometric functions, y=arcsin(x), y=arccos(x), and y=arctan(x). I definitely find it interesting to be able to take something like the 9th derivative without needing to know the 1st-8th derivative. I am wondering whether this is important in any way, or just a curiosity. I will easily admit the formulas are vastly unwieldly. Here is a link to the formulas:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ptl9tebqre

There is also one connection which I have no understanding of and would love some insight, when looking at the patterns of the coefficients of the derivatives of arctan(x), I found that they followed the pattern of the Lah numbers, and I'm sure there's some great reason which I couldn't find on my own.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations since you discovered the  regularized generalized hypergeometric function.

For example

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \sin^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{\pi }\, \, \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{n-1} \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{2-n}{2},\frac
  {3-n}{2};x^2\right)$$
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{\pi }\, \, \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{n-1} \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{2-n}{2},\frac{3-n}{2}
   ;-x^2\right)$$

Comment: Can you explain what the regularized generalized hypergeometric function is and where I can learn more about it? Also, my math teacher said that this is somehow related to Taylor Series, but I don't see the connection, do you know what he is talking about?